# Batch ErrorLevel: In For loop, calling another batch, calling SQL

Tags: batch-file, errorlevel

I've done a thorough search on this, but I can't find all of the pieces together;

I have:

```
BatchA runs for loop
   Calls BatchB
      BatchB runs a SQL script
         SQL Script raises error
      BatchB gets error, does (exit /b %ErrorLevel%)
   Batch A checks for error
```

I can't make the last step work, in which BatchA responds to the exit error of batch B.

I've simplified it, and I can't even get the following to work. By not work, I mean that the GOTO statement doesn't execute. I hate for loops in batch!!!!

BatchA

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /L %%i IN (0,1,0) DO (

:: Define variables
CALL SET TEST_NAME=%%TESTS[%%i]%%
CALL SET D_TEST=%%D_TESTS%%\%%TEST_NAME%%
CALL SET D_DB_RAW=%%D_TEST%%
CALL SET P_TEST=%%D_TEST%%\%%TEST_NAME%%.bat

:: Run preparation script
CALL ECHO. && ECHO.
CALL ECHO [INFO] TEST: %%TEST_NAME%%
CALL ECHO ----------------------------------------------------------
CALL ECHO [INFO] PREPARING THE DATABASE
CALL PUSHD %%D_PRE_TEST%%
CALL %%P_PRE_TEST_BAT%% %%D_DB%% %%D_DB_RAW%%
CALL POPD
CALL SET ERR_MSG="Error preparing the database before test: %%TEST_NAME%%"
if !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 GOTO L_ERROR
```

BATCH B

```
EXIT /b 1
```

Comment: What on earth are you doing? You enable delayed expansion, but then don't use it and use CALL ..%%var%%.. syntax instead. Your FOR /L DO loop is never closed, and even if it were, it is infinite. You cannot break out of an infinite FOR /L loop except by using EXIT (not EXIT /B)

Comment: i must agree, this batch seems like a ludicrous setup, all it accomplishes is setting vars over and over, and telling you each time it does. ?_?